# Pango Import is not working

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pango, windows64, pangocairo

I am very new into this python and its dependencies.
I'm trying to install Cairo and Pango,
I have successfully installed Cairo, Cairocffi, cffi, Pygi, and gtk+, and they are working just fine. 
I have tried many ways for the past three days to set up Pango, but it did not working at all.
FYI I'm using Windows 10 64 bit system and Python27

I've seen one tutorial from this site https://community.webfaction.com/questions/11481/how-to-install-pango-and-cairo-pangocairo-for-python
but it's Unix based, Is there any any I can do this in windows version?

and from other site, they said after downloading and installing I should compile pango and pygtk ? How can I do so in windows ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say,, but I'd suggest you start over with an install of anaconda, https://www.continuum.io/downloadsparticularly since you are using Windows.. Then using Anaconda install the other packages.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I did it but It still does not working

Comment: Whelp you have not provided any code, detailed description of what you have done / or error messages how is anyone to help?